# Ajax request to php variable does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am making an AJAX GET request, but the response I receive is not as expected. The response goes through, but the PHP variable is empty. Here is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $.ajax({
      url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      method: 'GET',
      data: {
         action: 'geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip',
      },
      success: function(response) {
         var country = response.country.names.en;
         var isoCode = response.country.iso_code;
  
         console.log('Country: ' + country);
         console.log('ISO Code: ' + isoCode);  
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
         // Handle any errors that occur during the AJAX request
         console.error(error);
      }
   });    
});
```

**UPDATED AJAX REQUEST FOR ANSWERS **

```
    $.ajax({
      url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      method: 'GET',
      data: {
        action: 'geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip',
      },
      success: function(response) {
        var country = response.country.names.en;
        var isoCode = response.country.iso_code;
  
        console.log('Country: ' + country);
        console.log('ISO Code: ' + isoCode);
  
        // Store the values in hidden input fields
        $('#hidden-country').val(country);
        $('#hidden-isoCode').val(isoCode);
      },
      complete: function() {
        // Retrieve the values from hidden input fields
        var country = $('#hidden-country').val();
        var isoCode = $('#hidden-isoCode').val();
  
        // Make an AJAX request to your PHP script in the theme
        $.ajax({
          url: '/wp-content/themes/bethub/inc/product_layout/side_block.php',
          method: 'POST',
          data: {
            country: country,
            isoCode: isoCode
          },
          success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            // Handle the response from your PHP script
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
        });
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        // Handle any errors that occur during the AJAX request
        console.error(error);
      }
    });
  });
```

In the console, as expected, I got the correct result without errors:

```
Country: Ukraine
ISO Code: UA
XHR finished loading: GET "https://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip"
XHR finished loading: POST "https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/theme_name/inc/product_layout/side_block.php".
```

However, when I want to output the result in a PHP file of the WordPress theme, I get an empty result:

```php
$country = $_POST['country'];
$isoCode = $_POST['isoCode'];
echo "Country: " . $country . "<br>";
echo "ISO Code: " . $isoCode;
```

What am I doing wrong?

The plugin that I am using is [geoip-detect](https://github.com/yellowtree/geoip-detect).

Server: Nginx php-fpm

No errors in the Nginx log.

Comment: are you even sending those parameter `country` and `isoCode` to your php?

Comment: `$country = $_GET['country']` - where is that GET parameter supposed to come from? Did you actually request your "PHP file of the WordPress theme", or the route that triggers it, _with_ a query string parameter of that name?

Comment: Your script sends the action to admin-ajar, which returns the country and isoCode. Those values are not in the GET request at all. Javascript runs after the page is sent to the browser, PHP runs before it's sent. So if you're trying to use `$_GET` in your theme template, it won't exist. You'll need o have javascript write/pass it wherever you want

Comment: When you make an ajax GET request, that means you are requesting data from the server into your js. That data is already present in your PHP and you are sending it from your PHP to your js. No need for a `$_GET[]` superglobal

Comment: have you tried retrieving the data in your PHP with the `$_POST[]` superglobal instead?

Comment: @ChrisG Yes. I tried this before, but no result. Updated my question.

Comment: @aynber updated code. No result.

Comment: you should call your second ajax in a `complete:function(){` after your first success. My guess is that you second ajax request is made before the 1st one finishes. Ajax request are asynchronous

Comment: If you're trying to get the variables in side_block.php, then it would be in `$_POST`, not `$_GET`

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, I tried to get the data of the global variable `$_POST`, empty. OK, I'll try using `complete:function(){` .

Answer (score 0):

Ajax request are asynchronous, which means that your second request is probably made before the 1st one even finishes so try making your second request inside a `complete function` after your first success like this

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
  method: 'GET',
  data: {
    action: 'geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip',
  },
  success: function(response) {
    var country = response.country.names.en;
    var isoCode = response.country.iso_code;

    console.log('Country: ' + country);
    console.log('ISO Code: ' + isoCode);
    $('#hiddenCountry').val(country);
    $('#hiddenIsoCode').val(isoCode);
  },
  complete: function() {
    // Make an AJAX request to your PHP script in the theme
    $.ajax({
      url: '/wp-content/themes/my_theme/inc/product_layout/side_block.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        country: $('#hiddenCountry').val(),
        isoCode: $('#hiddenIsoCode').val()
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        // Handle the response from your PHP script
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    });
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    // Handle any errors that occur during the AJAX request
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenCountry">
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenIsoCode">
```

Comment: It didn't work. The following error appeared in the console:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: country is not defined`
UPD: I declare var before first $.ajax . Error is gone, but variable in php is still empty.

Comment: not the cleanest of solutions but try assigning the values of `country` and `isoCode` to some hidden HTML elements and getting the values from those elements in your second ajax call

Comment: Thanks. hidden values are output correctly in result. `<input type="hidden" id="hiddenCountry" value="Ukraine">` But how I can get they in php?

Comment: you can make a function for your second ajax call and send the values from those inputs as parameters

Comment: True, you're right. I guess that's what I'm going to do. The strange thing is that the POST method didn't work.

Comment: I noticed that even when I try to pass a simple ajax or fetch request via post method, the request is sent but I can't call it with global variable $_POST[]. The cache is disabled. I have a feeling I'm missing something important or there's a problem with the server configuration.

Answer (score -1):

As was mentioned in a comment above, PHP is on the server, not client. $_GET deals with pulling in URL parameters that were passed to a php file from a form.

Since you are calling this library manually in php, you aren't on the client side. The function you used (fetch action) won't generate the same response. It will use the ip of the server making the request.

This means you should use `geoip_detect2_get_info_from_ip()` instead and feed in the ip address and other required arguments.

For info about the api for the library and what arguments are in the function, visit the repo here: [link to repo](https://github.com/yellowtree/geoip-detect/wiki/API:-PHP)

Comment: I read the documentation. The fastcgi cache is installed on the server. So I need to make an ajax request. `geoip_detect2_get_info_from_ip()` does not work for me because it displays a cached IP.

Comment: @Artem to clarify, it sounds like you are trying to call via the ajax and then display afterwards.  The Ajax happens after page load, php occurs before the load. If you want to update the DOM with your JS (assuming vanilla JS and not react or some other framework) you need to use DOM manipulation. This can be done with vanilla js or jquery. If I am still misunderstanding your situation, please elaborate on your goal more.

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, this is vanilla JS/jQuery. I'm still learning about asynchronous code and ajax, maybe I'm missing something important. I notice even when I send a simple ajax(or fetch) request via post method I can't call it with global variable `$_POST`. I have wp `function()`. Where I need to display result based on visitor's country (whether the service is available in visitor's country or not)

Comment: @Artem Ok, np. When you do an AJAX or fetch in JS, you are doing it after load of the page. Your PHP gets called before the load of the page. If you load the general page, then do an AJAX request to get some data, you can use DOM manipulation to update any given area on the page with the data you go from your AJAX. Where did you want to display the result? You can add an ID to your div or element and then in the success part of your AJAX, do something like `$(#yourDivID).html(result)` to set the result in the inner HTML for your element.